# How to save data in my db table with using contact form seven?

Tags: plugin-contact-form-7

I have a lot of input field and I'm using contact form seven. but let me know how to save the values of all fields in my db

Comment: You can use plugins like Contact Form 7 Database or any other. There are tons of plugins to choose from.

Comment: Ok thanks fuxia, after using recommended plugin can we check which file in execute insert query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Post My Contact Form](https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-my-contact-form-7/) plugin extension.   You can map your form to a custom post or an existing post type, and map individual form fields to custom post fields.

This is a lot more practical than CF7 Database as it allows you have each form submissions stored as a post and therefore reuse the WordPress functionality and admin dashboard to further manage your submitted data.

Comment: @Ganpatjanwa you're wc. Please select the answer/upvote it if it solved your problem.